# Sencha Touch: List detail .setActiveItem undefined

Tags: javascript, mobile, sencha-touch, extjs

Am putting together and app and attempting to get a list with a detail panel working. I have based it on the Sencha list video, but keep getting an error "TypeError: Result of expression 'abc.artistList.setActiveItem' [undefined] is not a function." when I try to click on an item and reveal the detail panel. The full code is below:

```
Ext.ns('abc', 'abc.panel', 'abc.store');

// Models _____________________________________________________________________
Ext.regModel('Artists', {
    fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
});


// Stores _____________________________________________________________________
abc.store.Artists = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Artists',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/abc/stores/artists.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
             root: 'artists'
        }
    },
    sorters: 'lastName',
    getGroupString : function(record) {
        return record.get('lastName')[0];
    },
    autoLoad: true
});

abc.artistDetail = new Ext.Panel({
            id: 'detailpanel',
            tpl: 'Hello, {firstName}!',
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'back',
                        ui: 'back',
                        handler: function() {
                            abc.panel.Artists.setActiveItem('artistList', {type:'slide', direction:'right'});
                        }
                    }]
                }
            ]
        });

abc.artistList = new Ext.List({
    title: 'Artists',
    store: abc.store.Artists,
    fullscreen: true,
    id: 'artistList',
    itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{firstName} {lastName}</div>',
    grouped: true,
    onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
        abc.artistDetail.update(record.data);
        abc.panel.Artists.setActiveItem('detailpanel');
    }
});

abc.panel.Artists = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    id: 'artists',
    title: 'Artists',
    layout: 'card',
    fullscreen: true,
    cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
    iconCls: 'artists',
    items: [abc.artistList, abc.artistDetail],
});

abcPrimavera = new Ext.Application({
    name: "abcApp",

    onReady: function () {
        var app = new Ext.TabPanel({
            fullscreen: true,
            animation: false,
            tabBar: {
                dock: 'bottom',
                layout: {
                    pack: 'center'
                }
            },
            items: [
            new abc.panel.Artists()]
        });
        }
});
```

Any help would be brilliant.

Thanks

Comment: Question answered on another forum - I have made corrections to above code so it should work.

Comment: Was it a namespace issue? You may want to post the solution as an answer to your own question for the benefit of the SO community. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.ns('abc', 'abc.panel', 'abc.store');

// Models _____________________________________________________________________
Ext.regModel('Artists', {
    fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
});


// Stores _____________________________________________________________________
abc.store.Artists = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Artists',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/abc/stores/artists.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
             root: 'artists'
        }
    },
    sorters: 'lastName',
    getGroupString : function(record) {
        return record.get('lastName')[0];
    },
    autoLoad: true
});

abc.artistDetail = new Ext.Panel({
            id: 'detailpanel',
            tpl: 'Hello, {firstName}!',
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'back',
                        ui: 'back',
                        handler: function() {
                            Ext.getCmp('artists').setActiveItem('artistList', {type:'slide', direction:'right'}); //updated code
                        }
                    }]
                }
            ]
        });

abc.artistList = new Ext.List({
    title: 'Artists',
    store: abc.store.Artists,
    fullscreen: true,
    id: 'artistList',
    itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{firstName} {lastName}</div>',
    grouped: true,
    onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
        abc.artistDetail.update(record.data);
        Ext.getCmp('artists').setActiveItem('detailpanel'); //updated code
    }
});

abc.panel.Artists = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    id: 'artists',
    title: 'Artists',
    layout: 'card',
    fullscreen: true,
    cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
    iconCls: 'artists',
    items: [abc.artistList, abc.artistDetail],
});

abcPrimavera = new Ext.Application({
    name: "abcApp",

    onReady: function () {
        var app = new Ext.TabPanel({
            fullscreen: true,
            animation: false,
            tabBar: {
                dock: 'bottom',
                layout: {
                    pack: 'center'
                }
            },
            items: [
            new abc.panel.Artists()]
        });
        }
});
```

Two parts of the code updated above - was using the wrong syntax to define the itemDisclosure.